# After upgrade Magento 2.3 to 2.4 can not add product to cart

Tags: javascript, addtocart, mini-cart, magento2.4.2

After click button **ADD TO CART** , it's error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'remove')
[image]

and mini cart is empty too
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems Magento Bug
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/31920

Please update this fix in your customer-data.js file
https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/5983e1733d56b1b2f15fb4f0e64094a3a4f3145d

Override customer-data.js
by copying vendor/magento/module-csutomer/view/frontend/web/js/customer-data.js to your theme app/design/frontend/VendorName/Themename/Magento_Customer/web/js/customer-data.js

Then update the Magento's github commits

Just remove the "remove" function and add the "initstorage" function

```
initStorage: function () {
            $.cookieStorage.setConf({
                path: '/',
                expires: new Date(Date.now() + parseInt(options.cookieLifeTime, 10) * 1000)
            });
            storage = $.initNamespaceStorage('mage-cache-storage').localStorage;
            storageInvalidation = $.initNamespaceStorage('mage-cache-storage-section-invalidation').localStorage;
        },
```

Note:
You are using Welpixel Custom module that already overrides the customer-data.js
You can update the customer-data.js by adding it here
app/design/frontend/VendorName/Themename/Weltpixel_Custom/web/js/customer-data.js